# objects - calling object instance inside a static method

Tags: java

```
public class create{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 Student myStudent = new Student();
 ...
 }
 public static String makeStudent()
 {
 student.set(x);
 student.get(x);
 }}


public Student{
...
}
```

Is it possible to call an object instance in a static method when the instance was created in the main method?

Comment: The whole point of static methods is that they are not tied to some instance and they are "Class level" methods. You can do it by passing this instance as a parameter for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether I understood your question correctly, If I got it wrong, please leave a comment.

add a parameter to your static function and pass your object to that function through the parameter.

```
public class create{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 Student myStudent = new Student();

 makeStudent(myStudent);
 }

 public static String makeStudent(Student student)
 {
 student.set(x);
 student.get(x);
 }}


public Student{
...
}
```